# ASP.NET MVC Google Charts with MVC database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-visualization

I've been stuck on this for a few days now.

I have a table called HoursPerSite created in SQL server. I am now using that table as a model in my mvc project.

I am trying to implement google charts to display the data from this table but so for the chart won't appear on my web app.

Here's the code:

Controller:

```
using HolidayTracker.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace HolidayTracker.Controllers
{
 public class MetricsController : Controller
{
    #region Index method

    /// <summary>  
    /// GET: Home/Index method.  
    /// </summary>  
    /// <returns>Returns - index view page</returns>   
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        GetData();
        LoadData();
        // Info.  
        return this.View();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Get data method.

    /// <summary>  
    /// GET: /Home/GetData  
    /// </summary>  
    /// <returns>Return data</returns>  
    public ActionResult GetData()
    {
        // Initialization.  
        JsonResult result = new JsonResult();

        try
        {
            // Loading.  
            List<HoursPerSite> data = this.LoadData();

            // Setting.  
            var graphData = data.GroupBy(p => new
            {
                p.SiteName,
                p.SiteHours

            })
                                .Select(g => new
                                {
                                    g.Key.SiteName,
                                    g.Key.SiteHours

                                }).OrderByDescending(q => q.SiteName).ToList();

            // Top 10  
            graphData = graphData.Take(10).Select(p => p).ToList();

            // Loading drop down lists.  
            result = this.Json(graphData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Info  
            Console.Write(ex);
        }

        // Return info.  
        return result;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Helpers

    #region Load Data

    /// <summary>  
    /// Load data method.  
    /// </summary>  
    /// <returns>Returns - Data</returns>  
    private List<HoursPerSite> LoadData()
    {
        // Initialization.  
        List<HoursPerSite> lst = new List<HoursPerSite>();

        try
        {
            //// Initialization.  
            //string line = string.Empty;
            //string srcFilePath = "Content/files/SalesOrderDetail.txt";
            //var rootPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
            //var fullPath = Path.Combine(rootPath, srcFilePath);
            //string filePath = new Uri(fullPath).LocalPath;
            //StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));

            //// Read file.  
            //while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            //{
            //    // Initialization.  
            //    Employee infoObj = new Employee();
            //    string[] info = line.Split(',');

            //    // Setting.  
            //    infoObj.FullName = info[3].ToString();
            //    infoObj.HoursTaken = Convert.ToDecimal(info[0].ToString());
            //    infoObj.SickLeaveTaken = Convert.ToDecimal(info[0].ToString());


            //    // Adding.  
            //    lst.Add(infoObj);
            //}

            //// Closing.  
            //sr.Dispose();
            //sr.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // info.  
            Console.Write(ex);
        }

        // info.  
        return lst;
    }

    #endregion

    #endregion
}
```

Script:

```
 // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.  
 google.load('visualization', '1.0', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });

 // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.  
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax(
{
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    url: '/Metrics/GetData',
    success:
        function (response) {
            // Set chart options  
            var options =
                {
                    width: 1100,
                    height: 900,
                    sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0,
                    legend: { position: "top", alignment: "end" },
                    chartArea: { left: 370, top: 50, height: "90%" },
                    hAxis:
                        {
                            slantedText: true,
                            slantedTextAngle: 18
                        },
                    bar: { groupWidth: "50%" },
                };

            // Draw.  
            drawGraph(response, options, 'graphId');
        }
});
});

// Callback that creates and populates a data table,  
// instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and  
// draws it.  
function drawGraph(dataValues, options, elementId) {
// Initialization.  
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

// Setting.  C:\Projects\HolidayTrackerMainProject\HolidayTracker - Working - 04-03 - Copy\HolidayTracker\Scripts/
data.addColumn('string', 'Site Name');
data.addColumn('number', 'Hours');


// Processing.  
for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
    // Setting.  
    data.addRow([dataValues[i].SiteName, dataValues[i].SiteHours]);
}

// Setting label.  
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([0, 1,
    {
        calc: "stringify",
        sourceColumn: 1,
        type: "string",
        role: "annotation"
    },
    2,
    {
        calc: "stringify",
        sourceColumn: 2,
        type: "string",
        role: "annotation"
    }
]);

// Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.  
var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById(elementId));

// Draw chart.  
chart.draw(view, options);
}
```

Where am I going wrong here? How do I get my webapp to display a simple bar or pie chart with data from the db.

Thanks

Comment: you are using 'POST' in your javascript but all your controller methods are 'GET'

Comment: I changed the javascript to GET and the chart still won't appear

Comment: can you add console.log(dataValues[i].SiteName) and check the console?

Comment: Forgive me but I've no experience really with javacript, where do I add that?

Comment: inside your "for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++)" loop

Comment: I added a breakpoint, ran the program and navigated to the page but debugging did'nt begin

Comment: At the breakpoint it mentions no symbols have been loaded for the doucment

Comment: check the browser console after you add console.log(dataValues[i].SiteName)

Comment: You debug JavaScript in your browser Developer Tools not in visual studio

Answer (score 0):

Chart for Salas For One Year

add This Action To Your controller

```
  public ActionResult ChartShow()
        {

            DateTime TM = DateTime.Now;

            DateTime FromDate1 = new DateTime(TM.Year, 01, 01);
            DateTime ToDate1 = new DateTime(FromDate1.Year, FromDate1.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(FromDate1.Year, FromDate1.Month));
            string S1 = db.TBLInvoices.Where(c => (c.INDate) >= FromDate1 && (c.INDate) <= ToDate1 && c.INActive == true).Sum(c => c.INTotal).GetValueOrDefault().ToString();

            DateTime FromDate2 = new DateTime(TM.Year, 02, 01);
            DateTime ToDate2 = new DateTime(FromDate2.Year, FromDate2.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(FromDate2.Year, FromDate2.Month));
            string S2 = db.TBLInvoices.Where(c => (c.INDate) >= FromDate2 && (c.INDate) <= ToDate2 && c.INActive == true).Sum(c => c.INTotal).GetValueOrDefault().ToString();

            DateTime FromDate3 = new DateTime(TM.Year, 03, 01);
            DateTime ToDate3 = new DateTime(FromDate3.Year, FromDate3.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(FromDate3.Year, FromDate3.Month));
            string S3 = db.TBLInvoices.Where(c => (c.INDate) >= FromDate3 && (c.INDate) <= ToDate3 && c.INActive == true).Sum(c => c.INTotal).GetValueOrDefault().ToString();

            DateTime FromDate4 = new DateTime(TM.Year, 04, 01);
            DateTime ToDate4 = new DateTime(FromDate4.Year, FromDate4.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(FromDate4.Year, FromDate4.Month));
            string S4 = db.TBLInvoices.Where(c => (c.INDate) >= FromDate4 && (c.INDate) <= ToDate4 && c.INActive == true).Sum(c => c.INTotal).GetValueOrDefault().ToString();

            DateTime FromDate5 = new DateTime(TM.Year, 05, 01);
            DateTime ToDate5 = new DateTime(FromDate5.Year, FromDate5.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(FromDate5.Year, FromDate5.Month));
            string S5 = db.TBLInvoices.Where(c => (c.INDate) >= FromDate5 && (c.INDate) <= ToDate5 && c.INActive == true).Sum(c => c.INTotal).GetValueOrDefault().ToString();

            DateTime FromDate6 = new DateTime(TM.Year, 06, 01);
            DateTime ToDate6 = new DateTime(FromDate6.Year, FromDate6.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(FromDate6.Year, FromDate6.Month));
            string S6 = db.TBLInvoices.Where(c => (c.INDate) >= FromDate6 && (c.INDate) <= ToDate6 && c.INActive == true).Sum(c => c.INTotal).GetValueOrDefault().ToString();

            DateTime FromDate7 = new DateTime(TM.Year, 07, 01);
            DateTime ToDate7 = new DateTime(FromDate7.Year, FromDate7.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(FromDate7.Year, FromDate7.Month));
            string S7 = db.TBLInvoices.Where(c => (c.INDate) >= FromDate7 && (c.INDate) <= ToDate7 && c.INActive == true).Sum(c => c.INTotal).GetValueOrDefault().ToString();

            DateTime FromDate8 = new DateTime(TM.Year, 08, 01);
            DateTime ToDate8 = new DateTime(FromDate8.Year, FromDate8.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(FromDate8.Year, FromDate8.Month));
            string S8 = db.TBLInvoices.Where(c => (c.INDate) >= FromDate8 && (c.INDate) <= ToDate8 && c.INActive == true).Sum(c => c.INTotal).GetValueOrDefault().ToString();

            DateTime FromDate9 = new DateTime(TM.Year, 09, 01);
            DateTime ToDate9 = new DateTime(FromDate9.Year, FromDate9.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(FromDate9.Year, FromDate9.Month));
            string S9 = db.TBLInvoices.Where(c => (c.INDate) >= FromDate9 && (c.INDate) <= ToDate9 && c.INActive == true).Sum(c => c.INTotal).GetValueOrDefault().ToString();

            DateTime FromDate10 = new DateTime(TM.Year, 10, 01);
            DateTime ToDate10 = new DateTime(FromDate10.Year, FromDate10.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(FromDate10.Year, FromDate10.Month));
            string S10 = db.TBLInvoices.Where(c => (c.INDate) >= FromDate10 && (c.INDate) <= ToDate10 && c.INActive == true).Sum(c => c.INTotal).GetValueOrDefault().ToString();

            DateTime FromDate11 = new DateTime(TM.Year, 11, 01);
            DateTime ToDate11 = new DateTime(FromDate11.Year, FromDate11.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(FromDate11.Year, FromDate11.Month));
            string S11 = db.TBLInvoices.Where(c => (c.INDate) >= FromDate11 && (c.INDate) <= ToDate11 && c.INActive == true).Sum(c => c.INTotal).GetValueOrDefault().ToString();

            DateTime FromDate12 = new DateTime(TM.Year, 12, 01);
            DateTime ToDate12 = new DateTime(FromDate12.Year, FromDate12.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(FromDate12.Year, FromDate12.Month));
            string S12 = db.TBLInvoices.Where(c => (c.INDate) >= FromDate12 && (c.INDate) <= ToDate12 && c.INActive == true).Sum(c => c.INTotal).GetValueOrDefault().ToString();

            string[] Modes = { S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6, S7, S8, S9, S10, S11, S12 };
            ViewData["OurSals"] = Modes;

            return View();
        }
```

Add View

```
 @{
    ViewBag.Title = "GoogleSalsChart";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="row text-center" dir="ltr">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="card-header">
            <i class="fa fa-table"></i> <b>Chart</b>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="row col-md-12">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
            <div id="top_x_div" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['bar'] });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

    function drawStuff() {
        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Chart', 'Total'],
          ["1",@(((string[])ViewData["OurSals"])[0])],
          ["2",@(((string[])ViewData["OurSals"])[1])],
          ["3",@(((string[])ViewData["OurSals"])[2])],
          ["4",@(((string[])ViewData["OurSals"])[3])],
          ["5",@(((string[])ViewData["OurSals"])[4])],
          ["6",@(((string[])ViewData["OurSals"])[5])],
          ["7",@(((string[])ViewData["OurSals"])[6])],
          ["8",@(((string[])ViewData["OurSals"])[7])],
          ["9",@(((string[])ViewData["OurSals"])[8])],
          ["10",@(((string[])ViewData["OurSals"])[9])],
          ["11",@(((string[])ViewData["OurSals"])[10])],
          ["12",@(((string[])ViewData["OurSals"])[11])]
        ]);
        var options = {
            legend: { position: 'none' },
            axes: {
                x: {
                    0: { side: 'top' }
                }
            },
            bar: { groupWidth: "90%" }
        };
        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('top_x_div'));
        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
         };
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it, for hours vs site?

Comment: yes You Can Do it By this code  string[] Modes = { S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6, S7, S8, S9, S10, S11, S12 };
            ViewData["OurSals"] = Modes; you can send this array to the Chart